# current date as argument in a task scheduled with celerybeatC

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I'm trying to setup a crontab task passing the date at runtime, like this:

```
 beat_schedule = {
    'mytask': { 
        'task': 'mytask',
        'schedule': crontab(day_of_week='mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat', hour=3, minute=0),
        'args': (date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')),
    },
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think Celery beat can do that. Workaround that comes first to mind is to write a tiny Celery  task that passes `date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')` to the `mytask`. Then you add that task to the Celery beat config instead of the `mytask`.